# group-by/aggregation over date ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

Got table ABC with one column. A date column "created". So sample values are like;

```
 created
 2009-06-18 13:56:00
 2009-06-18 12:56:00
 2009-06-17 14:02:00
 2009-06-17 13:12:23
 2009-06-16 10:02:10
```

I want to write a query so that the results are:

```
count    created
2        2009-06-18
2        2009-06-17
1        2009-06-16
```

Basically count how many entries belong to each date, but ignoring time.

This is in PL-SQL with Oracle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Technically, there is nothing in this question that is PL-SQL specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select count(*), to_char('YYYY-MM-DD', created) from ABC group by to_char('YYYY-MM-DD', created)`

Answer (score 11):

The TRUNC function returns the DATE of the DATETIME.

```
select trunc(created),count(*) from ABC group by trunc(created)
```

Comment: BTW, this answer will work for ORACLE, but SQL Server doesn't have that wonderful and useful function...

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, I'll add a generalized variant that works for arbitrarily defined bucket sizes:

```
  SELECT trunc( (created - to_date('2000.01.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD'))
                * 24
              ) / 24
         + to_date('2000.01.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD') theDate
       , count(*)
    FROM Layer
GROUP BY trunc( (created - to_date('2000.01.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD'))
                * 24
              ) / 24
         + to_date('2000.01.01', 'YYYY.MM.DD')
ORDER BY 1;
```

The query above will give you the counts by hour; use something smaller than 24 to get larger intervals, or bigger to create smaller intervals.  By reversing the position of the * and /, you can make your buckets be in increments of days (e.g. doing " / 7 " instead of " * 24 " would give you buckets of one week each.